# Terraform Azure Pipeline is not getting the workspace

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, workspace

I have a pipeline created in Azure Devops that uses terraform module. I have been able to run my pipeline but I'm having issues to detect the created workspace.

The pipeline tasks are described below:
[image]

The bash script creates the workspace in case it doesn't exist, here you can see the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "*************************************************************"
echo "*              Create or select workspace                   *"
echo "*************************************************************"

if [ $(terraform workspace list | grep -c "$1") -eq 0 ] ; then
  echo "** Create new workspace $1 **"
  terraform workspace new "$1" -no-color
else
  echo "** Switch to workspace $1 **"
  terraform workspace select "$1" -no-color
fi
```

I'm certain that the workspace has been created but the terraform subsequent tasks are not picking up the workspace.
[image]

You can see is setting **default** instead of **development**. This is is in `terraform plan` task

```
2021-03-12T18:13:48.0424826Z [1m  # azurerm_resource_group.k8s[0m will be created[0m[0m
2021-03-12T18:13:48.0426216Z [0m  [32m+[0m[0m resource "azurerm_resource_group" "k8s" {
2021-03-12T18:13:48.0427763Z       [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mid[0m[0m       = (known after apply)
2021-03-12T18:13:48.0428525Z       [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mlocation[0m[0m = "eastus"
2021-03-12T18:13:48.0429278Z       [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mname[0m[0m     = "default-k8s"
2021-03-12T18:13:48.0430000Z       [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mtags[0m[0m     = {
2021-03-12T18:13:48.0430713Z           [32m+[0m [0m"environment" = "default"
2021-03-12T18:13:48.0431181Z         }
2021-03-12T18:13:48.0431534Z     }
```

Has someone faced this issue before, if so any advice on having the terraform tasks detect the workspace that has been created in the bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a key detail in the bash script section. Which is the working directory where I wanted my scripts to be executed.

[image]
You can see that is in the Advanced section. Without that path the scripts were running in the wrong place.

As a result I have the **development** workspace and the resource group **development-k8s**.

```
2021-03-12T19:40:13.7898170Z [1m  # azurerm_resource_group.k8s[0m will be created[0m[0m
2021-03-12T19:40:13.7898875Z [0m  [32m+[0m[0m resource "azurerm_resource_group" "k8s" {
2021-03-12T19:40:13.7928911Z       [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mid[0m[0m       = (known after apply)
2021-03-12T19:40:13.7930291Z       [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mlocation[0m[0m = "eastus"
2021-03-12T19:40:13.7954850Z       [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mname[0m[0m     = "development-k8s"
2021-03-12T19:40:13.7955573Z       [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mtags[0m[0m     = {
2021-03-12T19:40:13.7956351Z           [32m+[0m [0m"environment" = "development"
2021-03-12T19:40:13.7956951Z         }
2021-03-12T19:40:13.7957351Z     }
```

I hope it saves you the several hours I spent going back and forth through the process :)